# setDisplayFrame causes crash with cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

In the init function of my CCLayer, I have the following code:

```
CCTexture2D *tex = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("img/menu/chest.png");
CCSprite *spr = new CCSprite();
spr->setDisplayFrame(CCSpriteFrame::create(tex, CCRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5)));
spr->setPosition(ccp(470, 90));
this->addChild(spr);
```

However, when I run it, I get an access violation on the "spr->setDisplayFrame" line. Why am I getting this access violation and how can I fix it?

Comment: What exact error do you get? Post it. Also, make sure `tex` and the return value of `CCSpriteFrame::create()` is not `NULL`.

Comment: The exact error is http://i.imgur.com/bWxyT.png , and I know tex and CCSpriteFrame::create() are not null

Comment: Run in debug mode and find out what exactly yields the access violation by single-stepping through the code.

Comment: I am, however at a certain point in the cocos2d-x library it clears the stack frame list and appears to jump to completely unrelated code, I can't follow it.

Comment: are you trying to debug the release build, or did you turn on any kind of code optimization in the debug build?

Comment: I'm debugging the debug build with the Visual Studio Debugger, and neither my project or the cocos2d project are set to have any sort of code optimization.